# Prevent SwiftUI from resetting @State

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I don't often understand when SwiftUI resets the state of a view (i.e. all that is marked with @State). For example, take a look at this minimum example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isView1Active = true
    let view1 = View1()
    let view2 = View2()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if isView1Active {
                view1
            } else {
                view2
            }

            Button(action: {
                self.isView1Active.toggle()
            }, label: {
                Text("TAP")
            })
        }
    }
}

struct View1: View {
    @State private var text = ""
    var body: some View {
        TextField("View1: type something...", text: $text)
    }
}

struct View2: View {
    @State private var text = ""
    var body: some View {
        TextField("View2: type something...", text: $text)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I'd want the two `TextField` to keep their content, but if you run this example some weird behaviours occur:

- If you run the example on the **preview** only the `View1` `TextField` content persists:

[image]

- If you, instead, run the example on the **simulator** (or on an **actual device**) neither the first textfield content, nor the second one persist:

[image]

So, what's happening here? Is there a way to tell SwiftUI not to reset @State for a view? Thanks.

Comment: For persistency use external view model (say, ObservableObject)

Comment: Hi @Asperi, thanks. I know that using an ObservableObject works and I'll likely go for that (even if I'd really like to understand why SwiftUI resets the (at)State in the example in the question). I think there's something we are missing here about the (at)State management.

Comment: `@State` is valid only while view inside view hierarchy. The way you created `View1` & `View2` is not valid from `@State` perspective, so you observe the issue, which you observe. Actually, you would observe the same if you'd place `View1` & `View2` directly in place, where you use `view1` & `view2` variables, again, because `@State` works only while the view is in view hierarchy. So, you just confuse yourself.

Comment: Ok, so it seems that the actual answer to my question is "`@State` is valid only while view inside view hierarchy" and this is sad because it has some important implications.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that `View1` and `View2` are being recreated every time `isView1Active` is changed (because it is using `@State` which reloads the body of `ContentView`).

A solution would be to keep the text properties of the `TextField`s in the `ContentView` as shown below and use `@Binding`:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var isView1Active = true
    @State private var view1Text = ""
    @State private var view2Text = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if isView1Active {
                View1(text: $view1Text)
            } else {
                View2(text: $view2Text)
            }

            Button(action: {
                self.isView1Active.toggle()
            }, label: {
                Text("TAP")
            })
        }
    }
}

struct View1: View {

    @Binding var text: String

    var body: some View {
        TextField("View1: type something...", text: $text)
    }
}

struct View2: View {

    @Binding var text: String

    var body: some View {
        TextField("View2: type something...", text: $text)
    }
}
```

---

Shown in action:

[image: GIF]

Comment: Hi George, thank you. Unfortunately what you are saying is wrong. In my example `View1` and `View2` are not recreated every time because they are `let` properties of the main view (you can easily test it by implementing their `init()` method. You'll see that it's called just once). And this is exactly the problem I raised in the question. Despite the view being exactly the same view (not recreated) the @State is reset somehow. When does SwiftUI reset a @State var? And Why? Is there a way to control it?

Comment: @superpuccio I see what you mean, and I'm not sure why. But this still looks like a solution to the problem you are having.

Comment: @superpuccio, George_E has the correct answer. @ State variables are not persisted between renders. So even though you may have the @ State in memory, the moment the view is removed from the view stack, those state vars are reset. You must use @ Binding.

Comment: I know this post is nearing 2 years ago now... But when I say `"being recreated every time"` I should more specifically say that the view `body`s are being _recomputed_, therefore the `init` isn't called multiple times. The comment above by Peter is correct.

Answer (score 1):

It `view1` and `view2` are completely independent and enclosure, like there is no `contextmenu`or `sheet`, you may use `ZStack` and `opacity` combinations.

```
 var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ZStack{
        if isView1Active {
            view1.opacity(1)
             view2.opacity(0)
        } else {
            view1.opacity(0)
            view2.opacity(1)

        }}

        Button(action: {
            self.isView1Active.toggle()
        }, label: {
            Text("TAP")
        })
    }
}
```